# TestContext via Spring.net?

Tags: c#, mstest, spring.net

I am running Test with the Visual Studio UnitTesting. I am injecting some Properties via Spring.net.

Because I am driving Data-based unit Tests I need to use the `TestContext`-Property to access the Data given with.

The Problem is the following: If I use the `TestContext`-Property Spring.Net doesn't work anymore (my properties are not getting injected). The same vice versa (Do not user `TestContext`, Spring.net does work).

Is there a way to use both? Or to fill my `TestContext` via Spring.net?

Adding Code:

```
 public BusinessLogic BusinessLogic
 {
     set { _businessLogic = value; }
 }
```

is set via Spring.

```
private TestContext testContextInstance;

/// <summary>
///Gets or sets the test context which provides
///information about and functionality for the current test run.
///</summary>
public TestContext TestContext
{
    get
    {
        return testContextInstance;
    }
    set
    {
        testContextInstance = value;
    }
}
```

should be set from MS VS 2008. But it just works either spring (the property is injected) OR my `TestContext` is injected. Not both...